# Cannot get dynamic view to update in browser

Tags: view, kohana

I've been trying to use a dynamic view in Kohana 3.2 without success. I'm using the following layout view with three views within that (meta, content, and footer).

view/layout:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php echo $meta ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $content ?>
        <?php echo $footer ?>
    </body>
<html>
```

I am able to initially render all three views with no problem (the $meta view has a default set of values within it), but later on in the flow I assign and pass variables to a new $meta view, but the view does not update in my browser. I enabled logging for that particular view (after the variables have been passed) and it appears that everything is fine.

```
// Passing variables to view and rendering view in controller/layout
$this->template->meta = View::factory('meta');
$this->template->meta->url = $this->template->art->url;
$this->template->meta->name = $this->template->art->name;
$this->template->meta->image = $this->template->art->image;
$this->template->meta->about = $this->template->art->about;
$this->response->body($this->template->meta);
Kohana::$log->add(Log::INFO, 'TEMPLATE VALUE: ' . $this->template);
```

How can I either force update a particular view within a view, or how can I replace a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the controller was being overridden by another controller. The original $this->response->body($this->template->meta) worked after disabling some of things down the line.

Thank you all for your help, it was greatly appreciated in working towards fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
$this->response->body($this->template->meta);
```

With:

```
$this->response->body($this->template->meta->render());
```

Comment: Again when I look at the log I still see that the meta view section has updated, but no visible change in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are extending Controller and not Controller_Template which would mean you need to tell the body to process the entire template.  Put this piece of code at the very end of your action and it will allow you to edit your meta, content or footer until you send that command.  You may be sending the body too early and then trying to change it which would be useless.

```
$this->response->body($this->template);
```